# C: Filling a matrix

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to fill a matrix with a for loop, however I'm coming up with a problem where any two coordinates x_0 and y_0 are interchangeable. To emphasize the problem I've simplified it down to the most basic example:

I'm filling the following 2x2 matrix and having it print the value at 1,2 (Or [0][1] within the array):

```
int matrix[1][1];

 for(j=0; j<2; j++){
   for(i=0; i<2; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &matrix[j][i]);
   }
}

printf("%d \n", matrix[0][1]);
```

However it always returns the value which is entered third, or [1][0]. I originally thought I might have messed up my for loop, but printing matrix[1][0] returns the same (although here appropriate value).

Thank you for any help

Edit: Added declaration.

Comment: How is `matrix` declared? Please post a complete, compilable, example.

Comment: Why don't you print the whole matrix, complete with indices?

Comment: `int matrix[1][1];` is wrong. You need [2][2] instead. In array declaration, you need to specify actual size (which is 2).

Comment: Also, don't use numbers in your array declaration. Either define them as const variables, or as macros, so that you can write `int matrix[N][M]` for example. This is considered better design as it allows you to be more flexible and it's less error prone once you have to undergo changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are confisuing indexing with allocation,

```
int matrix[1][1]
```

allocates a 1×1 matrix, and

```
int matrix[2][2]
```

allocates a 2×2 matrix where the `matrix[1][1]` is the actual *M*<sub>2,2</sub> element of the matrix, because the index of the *first-row,first-column* is *0,0*.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your matrix to be a 2×2 matrix:

```
int matrix[2][2];
```

When declaring a matrix, the numbers declare the size of the matrix, not its highest index (which is always one less than the size).

Answer (score 1):

the declaration 
`int matrix[1][1];`

is declaring 1×1 array. But you work with it as 2×2. Replace it by `int matrix[2][2];`

Comment: @iharob thanks. What black magic have you used for this symbol? :)

Comment: It's a html `&times;`, I know it from writing cross products when doing physics homework.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as if its working for me, and it looks correct.
try declaring matrix like `matrix [2][2];`

When I run it, I enter `1,2,3,4` printing `matrix [0][1]`, yields 2. 
which is correct.

Comment: may i ask why people down vote my answers? Is it my format of answering ?